# How do I ONLY run Meteor tests, and how do I NOT run Meteor tests

Tags: meteor

Trying to setup my integration flow and I have some tests that are quite destructive using the velocity-cucumber package.

First issue I find is that these tests are being run on the standard Meteor db. Which on localhost and dev is fine, but not so great for production. As far as I can tell the velocity-cucumber doesn't do anything with mirrors yet.

Because of this I have two cases where I need Meteor to launch in a specific way.

1) On the CI server I need for JUST the tests to run then exit (hopefully with the correct exit code).

2) On the production server I need Meteor to skip all tests and just launch.

Is this currently possible with Meteor command line arguments? I'm contemplating making demeteorize a part of the process, and then use standard node.js testing frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

**To run velocity tests and then exit**, you can allegedly run meteor with the --test option:

```
meteor run --test
```

This isn't working for me, but that's what the documentation says it is supposed to do.

**To disable velocity tests**, run meteor with the environment variable VELOCITY set to 0. This will skip setting up the mirror, remove the red/green dot, etc.:

```
VELOCITY=0 meteor run
```

Comment: I had noticed the --test flag, but couldn't seem to get it to behave the way I needed, and the docs seem a little unclear about whether it is running tests on a module or the project.

The VELOCITY param seems like it has a lot of promise. Will try that out!

Edited: Hit enter too soon.